# How to turn a set of lines into comments?

Tags: fortran, comments, block-comments

I know by putting ! at the beginning of a line it will turn into comment.
But how can I do that for a lot of lines?
Of course I don't want to do that by putting `!` line by line.

I'm using Fortran Powerstation.

Comment: BTW Powerstation is hopelesly obsolete, completely unsupported and well known to be full of bugs. I can't recommend using it in any way.

Comment: Current supported compilers have conditional compilation facility such as fpp or traffic.

Comment: With emacs, we can use "M-x comment-region" after selecting the lines to be commented out. "M-x uncomment-region" does the opposite. Another (non-fpp) way might be to insert "if (.false.) then" and "endif" before and after the region...

Answer (score 0):

There are no block comments in Fortran.

Read the manual of your text editor or IDE and find there how to comment and uncomment several lines at a time. In my editor (Kate) it is Ctr+D and Ctrl+Shift+D, for example. Your editor will be different.

In your Visual Studio try to press Ctrl + /.

Comment: I read the manual of my text editor (Microsoft Developer Studio) there was nothing about comment or uncomment lines, they just mentioned "!" at the beginning of a line. I wonder if they provide such a thing in Fortran Powerstation

Comment: Your manual must cpntain this information. Not in the Fortran section, in the general section. It simply must. Look for Keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+/ at all?

Comment: Yes I have, it doesn't work

Comment: I couldn't find any shortcuts related to comment or uncomment

Answer (score 0):

There are editors out there that do it. I use Notepad ++. Bear in mind that this will place a "!" at the beginning of each line, but it allows you to select your block of text and do it all at once.

If you are referring to HTML-style commenting where you enclose your block with <-- /--> tags, I don't believe that is possible, but it has been a while since I worked with Fortran.

Comment: Yes, in Notpad++ hold down alt and drag the mouse.  You can select a long column.  When you type ! it will appear across all selected rows.